# How to create variety of views in meteor client?

Tags: meteor

I'm wondering if we can provide different views with different URLs in meteor clients with the same server? That is, for a porker game, one view for each player.

A much clear example:

```
http://app1.meteor.com/myself # a web view for a user
http://app1.meteor.com/all # a web view for the administrator
```

Comment: I am unable to understand, Can you please edit questions with more specific information/details.

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you experience a problem while implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [router](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router). It is very easy to use.

You can find examples on usage [here](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just need to track user sessions. You can see an example of this here:

http://user-sessions.meteor.com/

and the source can be found here:

http://github.com/possibilities/meteor-user-sessions